# How do I show that the Dirac measure is countably additive?

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that the Dirac measure is countably additive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A_n$ are disjoint.Then at most only one can contain the point of mass ($0$). Therefore $$\delta(A_n)=0$$ for all $n$, except perhaps one of them for which it is equal to $1$.

If there is one for which it is equal to $1$ then $\bigcup_n A_n$ contains the point of mass. Therefore $$\delta(\bigcup_n A_n)=1=\sum_n \delta(A_n).$$

If none of them contain the point of mass so doesn't $\bigcup_n A_n$ and therefore

$$\delta(\bigcup_n A_n)=0=\sum_n\delta(A_n).$$

Notice we didn't really used the cardinality of the set of indexes. So, the Dirac delta measure is actually additive for any number of disjoints measurable sets.